# Total of group by divided by total of group by after where statement

Tags: sql, oracle, group-by

I get the total number after grouping by and the total of the filled rows after grouping by.

```
SELECT X, COUNT(*) as total
FROM table 
WHERE Y IS NULL 
GROUP BY X
```

This for example results in row 1 has 1000 values

```
SELECT X, COUNT(*) as total
FROM table
GROUP BY X
```

this for examples results in row 1 has 500 values.

Now what I want to get is the proportion. Meaning I want to get the total of my group by statement divided by the total of my group by statement with the WHERE filter. Is this possible?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You may use a case expression to count filtered rows in the same group by projection eg

```sql
SELECT 
    X, 
    COUNT(
        CASE WHEN Y IS NULL THEN 1 END
    ) as total_when_y_is_null,
    COUNT(*) as total,
    COUNT(
        CASE WHEN Y IS NULL THEN 1 END
    ) / COUNT(*) as desired_value
FROM table
GROUP BY X
```

Feel free to change the operations as desired.

Answer (score 1):

You need to join both Tables and have now access to both values

```
SELECT X, (total1/total2) As proportion
FROM
(SELECT X, COUNT(*) as total1
FROM table 
WHERE Y IS NULL 
GROUP BY X) As t2 

JOIN
(SELECT X, COUNT(*) as total2
FROM table
GROUP BY X) As t1 ON t1.X = t2.X
```